# ASP.NET MVC Action Parameters Not Binding when form sits idle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, wif, claims-based-identity

I am experiencing a strange issue with my mvc 5 web application that I can't seem to figure out.  The Application is an internal web app I've built for my organization.  Primarily it is accessed by employees who use domain connected computers but also will access via mobile devices and tablets.  I wanted to provide the former an automatic login experience through windows auth and AD (without having to enter credentials if they were already signed on  to the domain)  I also wanted to be able to provide all other users with a custom login screen rather than the browser native prompt.  To implement this I created a separate web app which authenticates the windows users and sends an encrypted cookie back to the main app with the user's roles.  Non windows based browsers are presented with a login page in the main app that authenticates against AD and retrieves the user's roles.  For each type of login the roles are than converted to claims and a federated token is created for the user.
My problem is that when a user logs in via the redirect to the windows auth app a strange issue is occuring.  Any form that I submit whether it be standard form submit or an AJAX post has to be submitted within a minute of loading the page otherwise the parameters sent to the controller action do not bind (null).  If a user logins in via the custom login page this problem doesn't exist.

Here is the code that performs the initial authentication in global.asax:

```
Protected Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest()

    Dim user As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User


    If user Is Nothing Then


        'First check if an authentication cookie is has been generated from the windows login
        'authentication app
        Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(".ConnectAUTH")

        If Not authCookie Is Nothing Then

            ' Extract the roles from the cookie, and assign to our current principal, which is attached to the HttpContext.
            Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)


            Dim claims As New List(Of Claim)
            For Each role In ticket.UserData.Split(";"c)
                claims.Add(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role))
            Next


            Dim claimIdent As New ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom")

            claimIdent.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName, ticket.Name))
            claimIdent.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ticket.Name))
            Dim claimPrinc As New ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdent)
            Dim token = New SessionSecurityToken(claimPrinc)
            Dim sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule
            sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token)

            HttpContext.Current.User = New ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdent)


            Return

        Else    'User hasn't been authenticated

            Dim ConnectBaseURL = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) & "/"
            Dim mvcPath As String = Request.Url.ToString.Replace(ConnectBaseURL, "")

            'If user is requesting the login page then let them authenticate through there
            If mvcPath.ToUpper.Contains("ACCOUNT/LOGIN") Or mvcPath.ToUpper.Contains("ACCOUNT/LOGUSERIN") Or mvcPath.ToUpper.Contains("SIGNALR") Then Exit Sub

            'for brevity i will omit the code below:
            ' Basically it checks whether the browser is windows based if so then it redirects the user to
            ' a windows login authenticator which authenticates the user against Active Directory, builds and sends
            ' an encrypted cookie with a list of roles/groups that the user belongs to.  When this function detects that cookie
            ' it decrypts it, sets up a claims identity, add the user roles and creates a federated authentication token

            'If the the browser is not windows based then it redirects the user to a custom login page which is tied to an MVC
            'action that will also authenticate the user against active directory and and set up the claims identity ...


        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Here is the code that authenticates the user if they are redirected to the custom login page:

```
        <AllowAnonymous>
    <HttpPost>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
    <OutputCache(NoStore:=True, Duration:=0, Location:=OutputCacheLocation.None, VaryByParam:="None")>
    Public Function LogUserIn(model As User, returnURL As String) As ActionResult

        Try
            If ModelState.IsValid Then

                If Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.PassWord) Then

                    'Call helper function to get all user roles and convert them to claims
                    Dim userClaims As List(Of Claim) = New LDAPHelper().GetUserGroups(model.UserName)
                    userClaims.Add(New Claim(ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName, model.UserName))
                    userClaims.Add(New Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.UserName))
                    userClaims.Add(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName))
                    Dim claimIdent As New ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "Custom")

                    Dim claimPrinc As New ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdent)
                    Dim token = New SessionSecurityToken(claimPrinc)
                    Dim sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule
                    sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token)


                    If returnURL Is Nothing Then
                        Return Redirect("~/")
                    Else
                        Return Redirect(returnURL)
                    End If

                Else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", "The username/password combination was invalid")

                End If



            End If

            Return Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            ModelState.AddModelError("LoginFailure", ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

I've tried eliminating the forms cookie from the equation by not sending it from the windows auth app and just hardcoding the claims and token creation after being redirected back to the main app. The HttpContext.Current.User object stays set as a valid claimsPrincipal each time Application_AuthenticateRequest is hit. I've implemented a Custom AuthorizeAttribute and the user is always authenticated and authorized.  The funny thing is if i hit the submit button on the form again immediately after the parameters passed through as null, it works. I've scoured online for a similar problem - nothing - i'm hoping someone on here has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be completely unrelated but I'm justtrying to help.  We had something similar.  When we switched from a web api in MVC4 to MVC5.  We had an AuthorizationAttribute that checked the token.  We read it, set the principal but when we hit the controller action, the principal was gone (in mVC5 - in the previous version this worked).  The short story was that it had to do with the async nature of MVC5.  We changed our way to implement another attribute that implemented IAuthenticationFilter (which is where mVC5 expects the principal to be set).
What this has to do with you ? I think you also have a problem with async and that you need to figure out in which event MVC5 *expects* you to set the principal (Application_AuthenticateRequest *might* not be the place).  Anything else might be set on the wrong thread and be gone when you arrive in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Willy for the idea but when you use a session authentication token you don't need to set the principal on every request.  Once the user logs in and is authenticated a session token is created for them with a claims identity/principal and it stays set until that token becomes invalid or they log out.  To be sure I checked the controller action and the user identity is still set but the parameters sent to the action are null.